# Servos Do Not Move to Specified Position

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

This code receives sine wave parameters from a serial connection, then formats and writes the sine wave positions to 8 servo motors.

The positions are successfully written to 6 of the 8 motors.

Of the two that don't work, I tried changing the motors to see if they were faulty; they are not. I changed the output pins to see if they were damaged; they are not.

I changed the order the equations are solved, and the positions are written to ensure there wasn't some bizarre timing issue. I saved a full cycle of the written positions and they output the correct numbers (i.e. the correct amplitude). You can see them here (format is "servo #" : "position"):

```
0:1779 1:1337 2:1750 3:1480 4:1357 5:1438 6:1452 7:1490

0:1779 1:1337 2:1750 3:1480 4:1357 5:1438 6:1452 7:1490

0:1779 1:1337 2:1750 3:1480 4:1357 5:1438 6:1452 7:1490

0:1779 1:1337 2:1750 3:1480 4:1357 5:1438 6:1452 7:1490

0:1779 1:1337 2:1750 3:1480 4:1357 5:1438 6:1452 7:1490

0:1779 1:1337 2:1750 3:1480 4:1357 5:1438 6:1452 7:1490

0:1779 1:1337 2:1750 3:1480 4:1357 5:1438 6:1452 7:1490

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1846 1:1404 2:1704 3:1434 4:1403 5:1484 6:1385 7:1423

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1880 1:1438 2:1630 3:1360 4:1477 5:1558 6:1351 7:1389

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1870 1:1428 2:1549 3:1279 4:1558 5:1639 6:1361 7:1399

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1819 1:1377 2:1485 3:1215 4:1621 5:1702 6:1412 7:1450

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1742 1:1300 2:1458 3:1188 4:1649 5:1730 6:1489 7:1527

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1662 1:1220 2:1474 3:1204 4:1633 5:1714 6:1569 7:1607

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1603 1:1161 2:1530 3:1260 4:1577 5:1658 6:1628 7:1666

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1582 1:1140 2:1609 3:1339 4:1498 5:1579 6:1649 7:1687

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1604 1:1162 2:1687 3:1417 4:1420 5:1501 6:1627 7:1665

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1665 1:1223 2:1742 3:1472 4:1365 5:1446 6:1567 7:1605

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1745 1:1303 2:1757 3:1487 4:1350 5:1431 6:1486 7:1524

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1821 1:1379 2:1728 3:1458 4:1379 5:1460 6:1410 7:1448

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398

0:1871 1:1429 2:1663 3:1393 4:1443 5:1524 6:1360 7:1398
```

The entire code is below. The relevant section begins after `if (Afreq > 0)` near the bottom. The positions that do not write correctly are pos[6] and pos[7]:

```
/*
This is a program that recieves sine wave parameters from a serial connection in a single string.
The string is parsed and converted into numbers, which are plugged into 8 sine equations to generate
positions for each joint of the robot.
*/

#include <Servo.h>

Servo SB, SF, HB, HF, EB, EF, KB, KF;
int iAmp, iF_offset, iB_offset, iFk_offset, iBk_offset, pos[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
unsigned int t = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
float fKnee_amp, fAfreq, fPhase, fGait;

void setup(){
  //Start serial stream at 115200 baud
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Connect servos to Arduino
  HB.attach(2);
  KF.attach(3);
  SB.attach(4); 
  EB.attach(10);
  HF.attach(6); 
  KB.attach(7);
  SF.attach(8); 
  EF.attach(11);

  delay(3000);
}

void loop(){
  char c, buffer[10];
  String readString, amp, knee_amp, afreq, gait, phase, f_offset, b_offset, fk_offset, bk_offset;
  unsigned int sine_time = 50;

  while (Serial.available() && readString.length() < 37){
    //delay to allow buffer to fill
    delayMicroseconds(100);
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
      //get one byte from serial buffer
      char c = Serial.read();
      //creates the string "readString"
      readString += c;
    }
  }

  if (readString.length() > 36){
    //see what was received
    Serial.println("The string is: " + readString);
    Serial.println(readString.length()); 

    //parse serial string into separate parameters
    amp = readString.substring(0, 3);
    knee_amp = readString.substring(3, 7); 
    afreq = readString.substring(7, 11); 
    phase = readString.substring(11, 15); 
    gait = readString.substring(15, 20); 
    f_offset = readString.substring(20, 24); 
    b_offset = readString.substring(24, 28); 
    fk_offset = readString.substring(28, 32); 
    bk_offset = readString.substring(32, 36);

    //convert string values to numbers
    iAmp = amp.toInt();

    knee_amp.toCharArray(buffer, 10);
    fKnee_amp = atof(buffer);
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    afreq.toCharArray(buffer, 10);
    fAfreq = atof(buffer);
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    phase.toCharArray(buffer, 10);
    fPhase = atof(buffer);
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    gait.toCharArray(buffer, 10);
    fGait = atof(buffer);
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    iF_offset = f_offset.toInt();
    iB_offset = b_offset.toInt();
    iFk_offset = fk_offset.toInt();
    iBk_offset = bk_offset.toInt();

    //clear strings
    readString="";
    amp="";
    knee_amp="";
    afreq="";
    gait="";
    phase="";
    f_offset="";
    b_offset="";
    fk_offset="";
    bk_offset="";
  }

  //if the joints should be oscillating
  if (fAfreq > 0){
    //determine joint positions
    pos[0] = iAmp * sin(fAfreq*t) + 1500 + iF_offset;
    pos[1] = iAmp * sin(fAfreq*t) + 1522 - iF_offset;
    pos[2] = iAmp * sin(fAfreq*t + fGait) + 1500 + iB_offset;
    pos[3] = iAmp * sin(fAfreq*t + fGait) + 1446 - iB_offset;

    pos[4] = iAmp*fKnee_amp * sin(fAfreq*t + fGait + fPhase) + 1500 + iFk_offset;
    pos[5] = iAmp*fKnee_amp * sin(fAfreq*t + fGait + fPhase) + 1581 - iFk_offset;
    pos[6] = iAmp*fKnee_amp * sin(fAfreq*t + fPhase) + 1500 + iBk_offset;
    pos[7] = iAmp*fKnee_amp * sin(fAfreq*t + fPhase) + 1538 - iBk_offset;

    //get time in milliseconds
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    //if the time threshold has been passed
    if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= sine_time){
      previousMillis = currentMillis;

      //write servo positions

      SB.writeMicroseconds(pos[0]); 
      SF.writeMicroseconds(pos[1]); 
      HB.writeMicroseconds(pos[2]);
      HF.writeMicroseconds(pos[3]); 
      EB.writeMicroseconds(pos[4]);
      EF.writeMicroseconds(pos[5]);
      KF.writeMicroseconds(pos[6]);
      KB.writeMicroseconds(pos[7]);

      //increment time parameter
      t+=1;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's the last two that aren't working, perhaps you've got a timing problem. Now I don't know how good the compiler is about detecting common code, but you might want to make it easier for it, and perhaps speed things up by making some temporary variables:

```
//determine joint positions
int pos01 = iAmp * sin(fAfreq*t);
pos[0] = pos01 + 1500 + iF_offset;
pos[1] = pos01 + 1522 - iF_offset;

int pos23 = iAmp * sin(fAfreq*t + fGait);
pos[2] = pos23 + 1500 + iB_offset;
pos[3] = pos23 + 1446 - iB_offset;

int pos45 = iAmp*fKnee_amp * sin(fAfreq*t + fGait + fPhase);
pos[4] =  pos45 + 1500 + iFk_offset;
pos[5] = pos45 + 1581 - iFk_offset;

int pos67 = iAmp*fKnee_amp * sin(fAfreq*t + fPhase);
pos[6] = pos67 + 1500 + iBk_offset;
pos[7] = pos67 + 1538 - iBk_offset;
```